# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Facebook PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

As soon i try to POST the page i've got this error when i will invite people to my event. I have read anywhere and tried everything, now i need help.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) thrown in /usr/extra/xxxx/xxx/public_html/src/base_facebook.php on line 1238
```

It's when i do this:

```
$facebook->api("/219507068176656/invited?users=" . $herZ, "POST")
```

`$herZ` is ids of users, ex. "*120394,39349034,293483484*".

Here is my sourcecode:
http://pastebin.com/sCFBPdpy

I cannot find out where the error is, because no other error is throwned.. Please help!

Comment: a guess..you have the create_event permission, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/312375168858626?browse=search_5017eadead76b7a22667493

Facebook addresses bugs when developers complain about them. At the link above you should report that you are experiencing the same problem as the author.